# Caching static data for asp net application

Tags: asp.net, performance, caching, web-config

I got a task to increase web site performance and when I took a look at server response I got 364kb response data of pure fear.

First of all I want to cash static data of application. 
I have Styles folder and /images, site.css inside.
For this purpose I have code in Web.config.

```
<configuration>
  <location path="~/Styles">
    <system.webServer>
      <staticContent>
        <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseExpires"
           httpExpires="Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 GMT" />
      </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

But when I checked response with firebug I got the same 364kb of evil and no expiration date on  year 2038.

What did I do wrong?

I am not using IIS or whatever. 
Only manual web.config, only hardcore.

Comment: `I am not using IIS` ... then what server are you using?

Comment: How are you running ASP.NET *without* "using IIS or whatever"?

Comment: ASP.NET Development Web Server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<system.webServer>` element contains IIS configuration.
ASP.NET Development Web Server does not read it.

If you want this to happen, you'll need to use IIS or IIS Express.